# Restarting a program in C

Tags: c

I've been working on a program that will add, search, edit, and delete a student record. While coding the main function (which contains the menu) I wonder if there is a way to restart a program if the user input a key that isn't included to the menu. So the plan that I have in mind is when the user inputs a invalid character the program will restart instead of asking to reprompt a valid character (because I'm working on a menu and I personally think it is neat). This is the program that I've been working on

```
int main()
{
    int choice = 0;
    do
    {
        system("cls");
        printf("MAIN MENU");
        printf("\n\n\n\t\t\t1.Add Student");
        printf("\n\t\t\t2.Search Student");
        printf("\n\t\t\t3.Edit Info of Student");
        printf("\n\t\t\t4.Delete Student");
        printf("\n\t\t\t0.Exit");
        printf("\n\n\n\t\t\tEnter choice => ");
        scanf("%d",&choice);
        switch(choice)
        {
        case 1:
            addInfo();
            break;
        case 2:
            searchInfo();
            break;
        case 3:
            editInfo();
            break;
        case 4:
            deleteInfo();
            break;
        case 5:
            displayAll();
            break;
        case 6:
            printf("\n\n\n\t\t\t\tThank you!!!\n\n\n\n\n");
            exit(1);
            break;




        }                                            //Switch Ended
    }
    while(choice==1 && choice==2 && choice==3 && choice==4 && choice==5 && choice==6);                                        
}
```

Comment: How can `choice` be 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6 at the same time? (Unless you're targeting a quantum computer.)

Comment: BTW, `while(choice==1 && choice==2 && choice==3 && choice==4 && choice==5 && choice==6);` will never be true. As there will be only 1 condition satisfied.

Comment: `printf("\n\t\t\t0.Exit");` versus `case 6:` exits. And there is nothing about the input `5` in the menu

Comment: So, instead of asking for new input, the user has to restart the program, just because you're worried about the "beauty" of the menu structure?

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want this instead:

```
do
{
  ...
} while(choice>=1 && choice<6);
```

In which case you don't need the exit() call inside the switch, you can place that part after the do-while loop.

Note that `scanf("%d",&choice);` leaves a trailing line feed character behind in `stdin` when the user presses enter. This will be a problem when you return to that line, because you'll read that line feed instead of the next integer from the user. Simplest way to avoid that is to add a single `getchar();` line after the scanf.

Comment: Notice the stylish open-interval `(choice>=1 && choice<6);`. That's the work of an expert and experienced programmer.

Answer (score 0):

It is going to provide a loop that works until the user entered 0

```
int main()
{
    int choice = 0;
    do
    {
        system("cls");
        printf("MAIN MENU");
        printf("\n\n\n\t\t\t1.Add Student");
        printf("\n\t\t\t2.Search Student");
        printf("\n\t\t\t3.Edit Info of Student");
        printf("\n\t\t\t4.Delete Student");
        printf("\n\t\t\t0.Exit");
        printf("\n\n\n\t\t\tEnter choice => ");
        scanf("%d",&choice);
        switch(choice)
        {
        case 1:
            addInfo();
            break;
        case 2:
            searchInfo();
            break;
        case 3:
            editInfo();
            break;
        case 4:
            deleteInfo();
            break;
        case 5:
            displayAll();
            break;
        case 6:
            printf("\n\n\n\t\t\t\tThank you!!!\n\n\n\n\n");
            exit(1);
            break;




        }                                            //Switch Ended
    }
    while(choice!=0);                                        
}
```

Comment: `while(choice!=0);` -> `while(choice)` although that's perhaps personal taste.

Comment: @Bathsheba It is always better to be clear in the source code. Even if C interprets any non-zero value as `true`, it is much better to show the intent, in this case `choice != 0`. It's the same with the omnipresent `any_type *p = ...; if (p) { ... }`, the "better" `p != NULL` looks much clearer.